# Depth and capacity selection in an Octree

Tags: data-structures, graphics, tree

Is their a general rule on what values to specify for the maximum depth and capacity of leaves when constructing an Octree?

Right now I am specifying these values experimentally, which seems a bit haphazard.

Comment: What are you storing in the tree? My guess is geometric primitives.

Comment: yes, triangles and their indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally want a decent tradeoff between depth of tree and how much granularity you want. For example, if you are doing this for culling purposes for rendering, if your tree isn't too deep, you'll be trying to render quite a bit of geometry that is outside your view frustum, but you also don't want it too deep since it will require more processing and will take up much more memory. So, it totally depends on your environment in both senses of the word - the nature of the in-game environment that the player runs around in as well as the "environment" that your games runs on (RAM, CPU speed, etc.).

Comment: So is the decision dynamic and would be made during runtime? e.g. perform a benchmark and decide based on that? btw, I am using this for ray tracing so I know before hand everything about the scene

Comment: I would do this offline if you can. On a game I worked on, it made sense to go no deeper than 3 levels for the octtree (basketball game environment). Any deeper would have been overkill. This was for PSP. For a ray tracing system, you probably would want to go pretty deep (assuming you have the RAM) since processing things outside of your view frustum would be pretty expensive.